# How to use class attributes/objects in another class

Tags: c#

Learning object oriented programming in class and got an assignment to make a pizza tracker. I don't understand how to use objects in other classes.

This program takes customers orders and estimates how long until the order is delivered. In order to estimate delivery time, my program will need to keep track of orders and employees. An order may contain 1 or more pizza's. Since it takes time to prepare the pizza, your program needs to track each employee's to-do list to get an accurate estimate of when the pizzas will get made.
The instructor provided us with starter code, I just have to make the classes.

```
namespace Assignment1
{
    // TODO Implement pizza tracker
    /// <summary>
    /// The main Pizza class.
    /// Contains methods for adding toppings to the pizza, the number of minutes
    /// required to prepare the pizza and a constructor that initializes the
    /// pizza's size to a given value.
    /// </summary>
    public class Pizza
    {
        Size size;
        List<string> toppings = new List<string>();
        double minutes;

        // constructor that initializes the pizza's
        // size to a given value.
        public void Pizzasize(Size psize)
        {
            size = psize;
        }

        // function that adds toppings.
        public void AddTopping(string top)
        {
            toppings.Add(top);
        }

        // function that gets the number of minutes to prepare a pizza.
        public double Numminutes()
        {
            if (size == Size.Small)
            {
                return 2 + (toppings.Count);
            }

            if (size == Size.Medium)
            {
                return 3 + (toppings.Count);
            }

            if (size == Size.Large)
            {
                return 4 + (toppings.Count);
            }

            return 0;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// The main Order class.
    /// Contains a method that adds a pizza to the order.
    /// </summary>
    public class Order
    {
        List<string> pizzas = new List<string>();
        double ready;

        // function that adds pizza's to the order.
        public void Addpizza(string pizza)
        {
            pizzas.Add(pizza);
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// The main Employee class.
    /// Contains methods for adding employees to the store, and for placing orders.
    /// </summary>
    public class Employee
    {

        List<string> makepizzas = new List<string>();
        public int Id;
        public string employeeName;

        public void employee(int id, string name)
        {
            this.Id = id;
            this.employeeName = name;
        }

        public void Addtodo(string pizzatd)
        {
            makepizzas.Add(pizzatd);
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// The main Store class.
    /// Contains methods for adding employees to the store, and for placing orders.
    /// </summary>
    public class Store
    {
        List<string> storeemployee = new List<string>();
        List<double> orders = new List<double>();
        string employee = Employee.employeeName;

        // Function to add an employee to the store. This function should
        // take an Employee object as a parameter.
        public void AddEmployee(Employee.employeeName)
        {
            storeemployee.Add(Employee.employeeName)
        }

        // Function to place an order. This function should take an Order object as a parameter, set
        // the order's field indicating how many minutes until the order is ready, and return the number of
        // minutes.
        public void Addorder()
        {
            storeemployee.Add()
        }
    }

    public enum Size
    {
        Small,
        Medium,
        Large
    }

    public enum Topping
    {
        Cheese,
        Pepperoni,
        Mushroom,
        GreenPepper,
        Bacon,
        Tomato,
        Ham,
        Pineapple
    }
```

Comment: Can you be more specific about exactly what you're trying to do?

Answer (score -1):

I don't really understand what you're asking but I think I might know.

It  looks like you want to something like this but still need to implement more logic:

```
namespace Assignment1
{
    // TODO Implement pizza tracker
    /// <summary>
    /// The main Pizza class.
    /// Contains methods for adding toppings to the pizza, the number of minutes
    /// required to prepare the pizza and a constructor that initializes the
    /// pizza's size to a given value.
    /// </summary>
    public class Pizza
    {
        Size size;
        List<Topping> toppings = new List<Topping>();
        double minutes;

        // constructor that initializes the pizza's
        // size to a given value.
        public void Pizzasize(Size psize)
        {
            size = psize;
        }

        // function that adds toppings.
        public void AddTopping(Topping top)
        {
            toppings.Add(top);
        }

        // function that gets the number of minutes to prepare a pizza.
        public double Numminutes()
        {
            if (size == Size.Small)
            {
                return 2 + (toppings.Count);
            }

            if (size == Size.Medium)
            {
                return 3 + (toppings.Count);
            }

            if (size == Size.Large)
            {
                return 4 + (toppings.Count);
            }

            return 0;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// The main Order class.
    /// Contains a method that adds a pizza to the order.
    /// </summary>
    public class Order
    {
        List<Pizza> pizzas = new List<Pizza>();
        double ready;

        // function that adds pizza's to the order.
        public void Addpizza(Pizza pizza)
        {
            pizzas.Add(pizza);
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// The main Employee class.
    /// Contains methods for adding employees to the store, and for placing orders.
    /// </summary>
    public class Employee
    {

        List<Pizza> makepizzas = new List<Pizza>();
        public int Id;
        public string employeeName;

        public void employee(int id, string name)
        {
            this.Id = id;
            this.employeeName = name;
        }

        public void Addtodo(Pizza pizzatd)
        {
            makepizzas.Add(pizzatd);
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// The main Store class.
    /// Contains methods for adding employees to the store, and for placing orders.
    /// </summary>
    public class Store
    {
        List<Employee> storeemployee = new List<Employee>();
        List<Order> orders = new List<Order>();
        Employee employee = Employee.employeeName;

        // Function to add an employee to the store. This function should
        // take an Employee object as a parameter.
        public void AddEmployee(Employee emp)
        {
            storeemployee.Add(emp)
        }

        // Function to place an order. This function should take an Order object as a parameter, set
        // the order's field indicating how many minutes until the order is ready, and return the number of
        // minutes.
        public void Addorder(Orer order)
        {
            storeemployee.Add()
        }
    }

    public enum Size
    {
        Small,
        Medium,
        Large
    }

    public enum Topping
    {
        Cheese,
        Pepperoni,
        Mushroom,
        GreenPepper,
        Bacon,
        Tomato,
        Ham,
        Pineapple
    }
```